# Как узнать соотношение сторон экрана?

Tags: javascript

Есть много форматов экрана , 16:9, 4:3, 3:2 и тд , как при помощи джс узнать формат ?

Comment: Самое банальное `screen.width / screen.height`.

Comment: А вообще, зачем?

Comment: Делаю верстку для игры, в игре можно менять формат экрана и если менять разрешение с 16:9 на 4:3 то все значительно меняется в плане отображения все становится шири при разрешении 4:3

Comment: @Young, А 21:9 учтете?

Comment: К сожалению мой монитор не поддерживает такое разрешение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поделить ширину экрана на высоту `screen.width / screen.height` и выбрать к какому стандартному формату результат ближе (`16/9 = 1,778`, `3/2 = 1,5`, `4/3 = 1,333` и т.д.).